# How to mock a function used in the object constructor (with Mockito)?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I need to write unit tests with Java for an Android application. What I currently need to do is to create an object Picture and use it for some tests. The problem with this object is, that it's constructor has a method call:

```
public Picture(File imageFile) {
    this.filename = imageFile.getName();
    this.imageDimension = getImageDimension();
    /.../
}
```

Method getImageDimension() references some other classes, therefore I would prefer for separability to just mock it's result. For mocking, I need to give Mockito a constructor, so it seems to me like a chicken-egg problem.

So, is there a chance to mock a function used in the object constructor with Mockito? If no, how could this situation be solved without changing the original code?

Comment: How does the Picture class get instances of "some other classes". It looks like those are the ones you want to inject mocks of.

Comment: @bowmore it calls Android framework MainActivity class that has a private static constructor. As far as I know it is tricky to mock it from a normal TestCase class.

Comment: Can't you hide that behind an interface, and depend on the interface so you can mock that?

Comment: @bowmore Hm, it can be possible, but I am not sure (MainActivity is the obligatory god (class) in the Android world). If I could do it, it would mean changing the original code and if I am deciding for changing the code, I could instead just add an additional constructor for tests to the Picture class. I was hoping for a magic technique so that I can leave the original code untouched...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you'd mock the entire object and not just a part of it. But if it's not final, create a subclass of Picture and override the constructor and do your custom thing there. That way you can avoid calling the original constructor and you can test the instance.

If it is final then unit testing it becomes quite hard. If you are not actually unit testing this particular class, you should either mock the picture object entirely or not at all.

BTW, this is why you shouldn't allow your constructors to do work: it results in code that is hard to test & mock. Separating object initializations from your logic is a good thing. Probably what you'd want here is an additional constructor that takes filename and dimensions as constructor args.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. :) I tried mocking the whole object (with success) and noticed that I had falsely expected Mockito to crash when it gets to the method in the constructor (somehow I thought that it cannot successfully mock the further references). So with that the question is solved. However, the Picture class is final and therefore I cannot mock the object with Mockito nor subclass it. I think I'll go with adding an extra constructor and creating the real object. PS - the code under test is not my creation...